# Run Gulp tasks web

Tags: forms, user-interface, gulp, task

Is possible to run gulp tasks from a UI page ?

Example: Having a web form or any type input and when you click on any button, to run a already defined and specific task(run build, compile sass, you name it.)

Thank you

Comment: afaik gulp tasks are meant to manage a project, not to be used in the application itself. What framework/language are you using?

Comment: I was thinking to use **reactjs**. What do you think ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: **I don't know, but if so, you shouldn't do it**.

Why?: Gulp is meant to be a task runner on developing side, running and controlled by a shell (terminal /command line), not on web / browser side.

You can use React with Gulp. Web behaviour is handle on React side. You can easily learn React, there are a lot of documentation and tutorials. I like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MhkGQAoc7bc)

Comment: Thanks! I know that gulp wasn't built for this. I just wanted to see if it's possible, and even it's possible is not worth it. **reactjs** looks more promising for what I want to achieve which is building/generating static html from a form. :)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you could. You just need to execute `gulp taskname` when needed. You would need an ajax request to a script that executes the gulp command.  F.I., you can make a working example with this skeleton, using nodejs and express:

**gulpfile**

```
    gulp.task('minify' , function(){
    console.log('gulp called!');
    gulp.src('scripts/src/test.js')
    .pipe(minify() )
    .pipe(gulp.dest('scripts/bin/'));
});
```

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express();
var exec = require('child_process').exec;


app.use(express.static('public'))

app.post('/send' , function(req , res){
    console.log('this was called');
    exec('gulp minify');
    res.send('success!');

});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

**public/index.html**

```
    <html>

    <head>

    </head>

    <body>
        <button onclick=send()>Execute gulp minify</button>
    </body>

    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>

        function send(){
            $.ajax({
                url : 'http://localhost:3000/send',
                method : 'POST',
                success : function(res){
                    console.log(res);
                },
                error : function(response){
                    console.log('Error!');
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

**package.json**

```
    {
  "name": "gulp-from-script",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

**scripts/src/test.js**

```
    function test(){
    console.log('this file should be minified to bin/test.js on click');
    //end.
}
```

With that boilerplate, you can just install the dependencies
`npm install`

then serve:
`node server.js`

And then go to
`localhost:3000/index.html`

After clicking the button, a minified file should appear under `/scripts/bin/test.js`

Of course you need nodejs and npm installed on your system to get this to work. Is just a working example demonstrating how to do it, it could be done with any other server side technology, the only point is to call the gulpfile task from a post controller on your server side.

So, **would this be useful for anything?** As Sandrina Pereira states, gulp is a task runner meant for building the front-end assets of your project. You shouldn't call it from a script fired by a user of a web application.

However, you could set up this kind of system to create a local website or app under localhost/ to manage your builds, or perform any other task in your machine, from a UI. I don't know if that is just a good or desirable idea, **but it is definitely doable**.

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer! I have to find a better solution for building/generating static html from a form. I was looking at **reactjs** and I think it's a good start. Thank you again.

Comment: IS there anyway to shoe console.log which is placed in gulp task?. i mean `console.log('gulp called!');` is this get diplayed in browser console